# LWC: Increased security for immutable @api properties but not documented in winter 20?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I noticed that the security for immutable @api properties is increased but unable to find any documentation.

Consider below LWC component:

HTML:

```
    <lightning-button variant="brand" onclick={sortFruits} label="sortFruits"></lightning-button>
    <template for:each={fruits} for:item="ft" for:index="ind">
        <div key={ft}>
            {ind}: {ft}
        </div>
    </template>
```

JS:

```
@api fruits;
sortFruits() {
    this.fruits.sort();
}
```

We should pass the array fruits from parent component like below Aura parent component:

```
<aura:attribute name="fruits" type="List" default="['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango']" />
<c:poc fruits="{!v.fruits}" />
```

When you click on button **sortFruits**, it will throw error

> Invalid mutation: Cannot set "0" on "Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango". "Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango" is read-only. at ReadOnlyHandler.set

**Solution:**
This can be fixed using `this.fruits = [...this.fruits].sort();`.

**Question:**
1. This started throwing error only in winter 20 upgrade and not before. Ofcourse, it is logical error but I do not find any documentation regarding this change so that our developers can do required changes in existing LWC components - not just for sort() but also for any other potential JS functions where code can break
2. When I say `this.fruits =`, I am actually modifying the data which came from parent. This is working today, but will this work in future? And is reassigning not same as mutating data - in what way they are different?

Comment: IMHO `@api` is designed to be read-only, in-only stuff coming down to your component. You should be able to raise events that should be caught in the different component. e.g. modifying data in another component is always a bad idea.

Comment: @zaitsman, I agree it is read-only. But I wonder why its even working for `this.fruits =` even after security upgrade. I am more concerned about the communication of such changes through documentation as mentioned in 2 points in Question end.

Comment: You are not modifying the data in the parent, you're modifying it in-scope. It works for the same reason that you can do this in your browser: `console.log = function(a) { alert(a); }` -> javascript allows you to redefine anything, which is why it is slo fragile.

Comment: My guess: API properties used to receive clones of the given values but this was changed to improve performance to accept the given value directly. Much of the time this would have no impact, but you found a case where it does - inline array (and other?) definitions in Aura markup get frozen to maintain appropriate behaviour (and probably always were). Now that LWC doesn't clone you see an undocumented  behaviour change. Just a guess...

Comment: @PhilW, If it used to receive clones then even `push` should have worked earlier - but it never worked. If its undocumented, its a big worry as all native JS developers would just use `array.sort()` BUT not `array = [...array].sort()` and it basically breaks existing code. I hope somebody comes up with documentation.

Comment: We don't use Aura with our LWCs and have actually never noticed API properties to be frozen (immutable).

Something worth considering regardless of whether the API properties were or were mutable is that an array-type API property is only reactive if you actually change the array - doing things like push change the array content but do not cause reactive behaviour, whereas doing something like concat or using a spread operator not only updates the content but actually replaces the array property's value entirely (and trigger reactive behaviour).

Comment: (I think the reason we didn't notice is because we always treat them as such - they are inputs only for our components and we use internal state initialized from these values as needed instead)

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can find (in the [LWC dev guide](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript_reactive)) is:

> A component that declares a public property can set only its default value. In our example, the example-todo-item component can’t update the value of the itemName property in the todoItem.js file.

Answer (score 1):

@salesforce-sas Reassigning is not same as mutable. The reason being, an array is reference type so if you mutate a reference type it will reflect everywhere. Hence, will also change the value at the parent (which is not intended because we want one way binding). `[...this.fruits].sort()` this statement creates a new address/reference and then performs sort. Hence, you are sorting a copy of array and this will not change parents copy (which is intended behaviour).
Hope that is helpful.